# Integration Question involving the Divergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm doing some practice questions for an upcoming test, but I got stuck on one.  It says "Let $\text{div}(F)=x^2+y^2+z^2+3$. Calculate $$\int\int_{S_1}f\cdot\textbf{n}\ dA,$$ where $S_1$ is the sphere of radius 1 centered at the origin."

I've tried it for what feels like five different ways, and got it wrong every single time, with different answers most of the time.  I've tried integrating directly, and changing to polar co-ordinates, but still no luck.  It is clear to me that I have to use the Divergence Theorem, though.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried spherical coordinates? The resulting triple integral should be fairly straightforward then.

Comment: I did try spherical co-ordinates, but looking at the answer below, I must have just made a calculation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like $\int\int\int_B(x^2+y^2+z^2+3)\operatorname dx\operatorname dy\operatorname dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1(r^4+3r^2)\sin\theta\operatorname dr\operatorname d\theta\operatorname d\varphi$ etc...

Comment: $x^2$+$y^2$+$z^2$=$r^2$

Comment: Right.  But there's also an $\operatorname dV=r^2\sin\theta\operatorname dr\operatorname d\theta\operatorname d\varphi $, isn't there?  @JG123

Comment: You are correct. I thought it was $r$, not $r^2$...

Comment: I also thought it was an $r$, instead of an $r^2$.  Thank you!